# Defining multiplication on the tensor product of $R$-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

If $M$ and $N$ are $R$-algebras, then one can define a multiplication of elementary tensors as follows; $(m \otimes n) \cdot (m' \otimes n') = mm' \otimes nn'$.

My question is how can we show, using the universal property of the tensor product, that this is a well defined operation?

My understanding is that we would be need a 4-linear map out of $(M \times N)\times (M \times N)$ into $M \otimes N$, that would factor through $(M \otimes N) \otimes (M \otimes N)$ giving us the required linear map.

Am I on the right track? I can't seem to get my head around the details in the proof. Any pointers would be of great help to me.

Comment: Do you specifically need to use the universal property? It seems easier to just show it the old-fashioned way.

Comment: No I suppose not, that is just how I thought I would tackle the problem

Comment: Well then, I will answer it in the old-fashioned way. I'm not sure if the universal property is useful here(even though I very well could be wrong) since you're not trying to show something about the tensor product, you're trying to show something about the multiplication.

Comment: What *is* the old-fashioned way?

Comment: @ the original question: For any $m \in M$ and $n \in N$, show that the map sending $\left(m',n'\right) \mapsto mm' \otimes nn'$ is $R$-bilinear. Thus it leads to a linear map $m' \otimes n' \mapsto mm' \otimes nn'$. Denote this map by $G_{m,n}$. Show that this map $G_{m,n}$ depends $R$-bilinearly on $m$ and $n$ (this requires checking some identities between linear maps -- recall that you only need to check them on pure tensors). Thus, we have an $R$-linear map which sends $m \otimes n$ to $G_{m,n}$.

Comment: Is it an isomorphism though? Does it need to be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the first paragraph of Bourbaki, A.III.4.1.